# formula that will tell me how many sets of 7-consecutive-zero's there are in each row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a database with 300 rows and 50 columns.

The cells are populated with either `zero`, `one` or `blank`.

I'm looking for a formula that I can plug into column 51 for the 300 rows, that will tell me how many sets of *7-consecutive-zero's* are there in each row.

Comment: So if you have `7X0 1 1 7X0` it should count two? What about if you've 0 8 times, should it count one or two?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following *User Defined Function*:

```
Public Function BlockCount(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim ItemCount As Long, r As Range, v As String

    BlockCount = 0
    ItemCount = 0

    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Text
        If v = "0" Then
            ItemCount = ItemCount + 1
            If ItemCount = 7 Then
                ItemCount = 0
                BlockCount = BlockCount + 1
            End If
        Else
            ItemCount = 0
        End If
    Next r

End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=BlockCount(A1:Z1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**